# Detecting when user changes custom color settings in colordialog

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How do I detect when the user has changed the colors in the custom colors in colordialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try recording the CustomColors() property of the ColorDialog before you display the dialog box in an Integer arrays
Then, after you've shown the dialog, compare the CustomColors property with the integer array.